# android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel

Tags: java, android

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure from system
android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon (ContextImpl.java:1388)
android.app.ContextImpl.startService (ContextImpl.java:1321)
android.content.ContextWrapper.startService (ContextWrapper.java:606)
com.google.firebase.iid.f.a ()
com.google.firebase.iid.f.a ()
com.google.firebase.iid.f.b ()
com.google.firebase.iid.f.a ()
com.google.firebase.iid.d.c ()
com.google.firebase.iid.d.b ()
com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.a ()
com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.e ()
com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.a ()
com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.b ()
com.google.firebase.iid.b$2.run ()
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

Caused by android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died

```
android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative (Binder.java)
android.os.BinderProxy.transact (Binder.java:503)
android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startService (ActivityManagerNative.java:4450)
android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon (ContextImpl.java:1371)
android.app.ContextImpl.startService (ContextImpl.java:1321)
android.content.ContextWrapper.startService (ContextWrapper.java:606)
com.google.firebase.iid.f.a ()
com.google.firebase.iid.f.a ()
com.google.firebase.iid.f.b ()
com.google.firebase.iid.f.a ()
com.google.firebase.iid.d.c ()
com.google.firebase.iid.d.b ()
com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.a ()
com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.e ()
com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.a ()
com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.b ()
com.google.firebase.iid.b$2.run ()
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

its as strange bug as it gets, i saw it in my firebase account.and have no clue which of my java code is the error in.

Comment: It does not look like it is in any of your code, but rather in a Firebase library.

Comment: Does this issue happen continuously ?

Comment: Hi there. Did you found any solution for this error?

Comment: looking for solution too